# how to patch stockdata into firebase using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, patch

I have done a simple webstore with localStore and Firebase. I want that the stock (lager) updates in firebase after checkout. When I push the button checkout it should patch the new stock(lager) data. I have got so the console shows the new stock but I cant make the new stockdata to patch to firebase. So in firebase its the new updated stockdata (lager).

> ```
> //checkout
> function checkout(id){
>         let cartItemsObj = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart')
>         cartItemsObj = JSON.parse(cartItemsObj)
>         
>         let cartArray = Object.values(cartItemsObj)
>         console.log(cartArray )
>         let index = ''
>         cartArray.map((item) =>{
>           index= item.id
>           console.log('DATA OBJ ID', index)
>         })
>        
>       
>         
>   //index är undefined
>   async function patchPost(obj){
>     const baseURL = `https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/`
>     const url = baseURL + `Products${index}.json`
>         const init = {
>             method: 'PATCH',
>             body: JSON.stringify(obj),
>             headers: {
>                 "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
>             }
>         };
>     
>         const response = await fetch(url, init)
>         const data = await response.json()
>         console.log(data)
>         
>     }
>     
>     let obj = cartArray.map(item =>{
>       let newLager = item.lager - item.inCart
>       console.log(newLager)
>       if(item.id === id){
>       }
>         return{
>         
>           lager: newLager
>         }
>       
>     })  
>  
>     // let obj = cartArray.reduce(function(acc, cur, ndex) {
>     //   acc[ndex] = cur;
>     //   return acc[ndex];
>     // }, {});
>
>     patchPost(obj)
>     console.log(obj)
>    
>     
>   }
> ```

I get error in the console about the patched data
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your code and screenshot, you are sending an array of data in the body of the PATCH request. That is not valid for a patch request, which should (afaik) always be an object with keys and values of the specific keys/paths you want to write in the database. E.g.

```
{
  "/path/to/lager1": 9,
  "/path/to/lager2": 8
}
```